# Starbucks to English

Tags: code-golf

In the classic days of Starbucks before these newfangled sticker-printers and wireless drivethrough headset palmtop scanner dealies, in the heady days of 2000-ish, Starbucks had a concise system for describing beverages with a strict syntax and accompanying encoded form.

Vertically on the cup there are a series of labelled boxes which may contain certain values.:

```
Decaf
[   ]     -blank-  X  1/2  1/3  2/3
Shots
[   ]     -blank-  0 1 2 3 ... 20    followed by    S T G V
Syrup
[   ]     -blank-  V M C H
Milk
[   ]     -blank-  Wh % N B
Custom
[    ]    -blank- ((-|x)?(F|WC|M|CR) )+
Drink
[   ]     E EM ECP A L C CM
```

But we will use a horizontal form for easier manipulation. These are the names of the 6 fields of the input which may be any convenient form. Examples here are simple CSV. The Custom field and Syrup fields each may be a concatenation of several values. You may use any convenient subdelimiter. Examples here use space. The Shots field is also a concatenation of a (possible) number and a designation of the cup size (which is implicit in the physical cup but naturally fits in this place in the encoding).

The Decaf field values are translated into words like this

```
-blank-   -nothing-
X         "decaf"
1/2       "half-caf"
1/3       "one-third-caf"
2/3       "two-thirds-caf"
```

Logically, the fractional values are only permissible when the number of shots is divisible by the denominator; but for this challenge it is not necessary to detect or diagnose this error.

The Shots field should be broken into its numerical component (if present) and the size identifier. The number should be displayed in latin tuple form: single, double, triple, quadruple, quintuple, *beyond 5 just print the number and the suffix "-tuple" ie. `7-tuple`, `16-tuple`*. The size designations are:

```
S  short
T  tall
G  grande
V  venti
```

Eg.

```
2T  double tall
3G  triple grande
```

The Syrup field may contain one or more of several optional-number/lettercode tokens. The maximum number of a syrup is 20. Even that is too much. LOL.

```
V  vanilla
C  caramel
M  mocha
H  hazelnut
```

Eg.

```
2V 2C     two vanilla two caramel
H         hazelnut
M H 1V    mocha hazelnut one vanilla
```

The Milk field may contain **one** of the following.

```
Wh  whole-milk
%   two-percent
N   skim
B   breve
```

The Custom field may contain one or more of several modifiers with optional `x` or `-` sign.

```
x  extra     F   foam
-  no        WC  whip
             M   mocha drizzle
             CR  caramel drizzle
```

The Drink field contains one drink id.

```
E    espresso
EM   espresso macchiato
ECP  espresso con panna
A    americano
L    latte
C    cappuccino
CM   caramel macchiato
```

Any field may be blank except for the size designation and the drink id.

Examples.

```
,3G,V,Wh,,L    =>   triple grande vanilla whole-milk latte
X,2T,,N,,L     =>   decaf double tall skim latte
1/2,V,,,,CM    =>   half-caf venti caramel macchiato
2/3,3V,3V,B,WC,L  => two-thirds-caf triple venti three vanilla breve whip latte
,G,,,xCR,CM    =>   grande extra caramel drizzle caramel macchiato
X,4T,2M 2C,B,xWC -F xM,C  =>
  decaf quadruple tall two mocha two caramel breve extra whip no foam extra mocha drizzle cappuccino
```

There is no need to diagnose erroneous or illogical concoctions such as a "no foam ... cappuccino*.

### Additional Complication

For only the drinks with the word `espresso`, the number `single` should be replaced by `solo` and `double` should be replaced by `doppio`. And the size may be unspecified and omitted. Also, just for the bare `espresso` drink itself, if the only other specification is one of these two specially-replaced numbers-of-shots, then the word `espresso` itself should be omitted.

```
,2,1V,B,,EM   =>  doppio one vanilla breve espresso macchiato
,1,,,,E       =>  solo
,2,,,,E       =>  doppio
,3,,,,E       =>  triple espresso
```

### Additional observations on 'reading a cup'

This part is not a requirement for this challenge but may be a useful refinement in applying this sort of verbalized system in other domains.

I mentioned *syntax* at the very beginning, and by applying the schema to incoming streams of words, orders could be transmitted verbally by several order takers to the barista making beverages. The rough framework `SIZE .... DRINK` provides demarcation between several orders spoken at once. There is thus a tendency to make all the interior attributes as adjectival phrases so the order also has a valid English noun-phrase structure. So `whip` is often spoken `with whip` or `whipped` and `foam` is often spoken `foamy` or `with foam`.

Thus, for some [old-time baristas](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/users/959/), they're not "correcting you" when they repeat the order in the proper format (*well,... sometimes*). They're simply organizing the information for the purpose of remembering all the details exactly. By schematizing the information, an entire beverage order becomes a single unit for the purpose of applying [the magic number 7 plus or minus 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magical_Number_Seven,_Plus_or_Minus_Two). So a barista with this skill can *hold 5-9 orders in their head* provided other distractions do not consume too much head room. :)

Comment: I'm glad you referred to these as beverages, rather than coffee.

Comment: What do you mean newfangled. Unless I'm ordering from mobile, all the Starbucks baristas I've ever seen still write it down with a black marker.

Comment: @JoeZ. Just my frustration that the simplicity of the old way is continually eroded. The baristas themselves have to translate to a third form in the way of inputting the order to the system. And for a store with a drive-thru, the order is printed in a fourth form on the sticker. Whereas the listing on the heads-up queue has a fifth distinct format (omitting all syrup numbers).

Comment: s/frustration/lamentation/

Comment: "Venti is large" **no**, [Large is large. In fact, tall is large and grande is Spanish for large. Venti is the only one that doesn't mean large. It's also the only one that's Italian. Congratulations, you're stupid in three languages.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1c9HQgeGhd0) :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 640 bytes

Performs a series of substitutions to transform the input into the expected output.

```
-
no 
x
extra 
Wh
whole-milk
%
2-percent
N
skim
B
breve
X
deJ
1/2
half-J
1/3
1Q-J
2/3
2Qs-J
Q
-third
J
caf 
^,
 ,
 ,1(?=\D.*E)
,soloZ
 ,2(?=\D.*E)
,doppioZ
Z,,,,E$
Z
 ,(\d+)
,$1UleZ
,1U
,sing
,2U
,doub
,3U
,trip
\d+(?!\d*U)
$&Y 
U
-tup
,4-.
,quadr
,5-
,quin
 ,
Z
S
short
T
tall
G
grande
ZV
 venti
M(?=[^,]*,\w*$)
MR
E
espresso
M$
 macchiato
CP
 con panna
A
americano
L
latte
C$
cappuccino
F
foam
WC
whip
R
 drizzle
4Y
fourY
6Y
sixY
7Y
sevenY
9Y
nineY
10Y
ten
11Y
eleven
12Y
twelve
13Y
thirK
15Y
fifK
18Y
eighK
20Y
twenty
1Y
one
2Y
two
3Y
three
5Y
five
8Y
eight
1(\w*)Y
$1K
K
teen
V
vanilla
C
caramel
M
mocha
H
hazelnut
 -
-
Z,*| ?,+
 
^ |Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVPvT9swEP3@/gpPKlNbLqxOW9g@TGhkpYgSNH40JV2HZhJDLFInS1LoEP97d64mRNSoz@/du7N9l0o3xqrNTnv8e@PBFgJr6HVTKYFZhuesyLW3NPkjduB7pa4SbRuco340SxzhrtJPGjdI9SnkJx@Zyu89B/uQFwx8Bv5FzegCXpOZKsUpEnUvcEsQ7ifbh18X3/e6ow6oLvJizpz/jkuLsjTMzomfUQtOby/SXZZacprrOUhO2WrsA8ifOsPqDtRn1FSmBIe2Dz8s0u60g9bHWGDKG1mVoIG3B/qzUmkFGnoOGuu2NMcV6qyoGlyjUXmOMR4qZVONeQTxxMc3CHmDP2/pV5cWz91WB@ElRtB1Wem6LhC2IJYqSTKjmgLBD4iksKJU1ip8g1rqyiTKFjhDrppGI2jxlZTlKkkMs8e4L9QSs4Avn/d/CZFW5uUl1xjELK2qGPsxarOOccD/fP82xpcY1lgdQ/ZiNNpCyhg6dyKkz9SzzrlRss@QuzCBHHIyc8/gMweah2wCv7eNs81fsLmwGltjga2p0hpbD6f5b2kg23z@ToyWnGDCdblahCdlTZ4rBHyqik@bI8SySDKFE56PF53bVQPhweOedl/FIe2Cx0G8xthsbkjuR3QQ0SyjYxrhhobRlnpbD3g9fLd2ohy8EdQfUyD8SITixHE0CjnIvyY6JzpzM0qRm6QgdLNJfTbze0SzgFUas7IOLp3Kla5J9kLh9wLW17NAeMdiHQon86SRdDaXnuR2NLnPzDrEzBvocRLOEXD5rZXj@eMg/4oiEYiQdoizejMHOcM/)

Most of it is pretty straightforward replacements. A few interesting parts are:

```
 ,1(?=\D.*E)
,soloZ
 ,2(?=\D.*E)
,doppioZ
```

Handles the special cases for drinks containing the word "espresso". It transforms the 1 and 2 into "solo" and "doppio" before we get to the stage where we transform those numbers into latin tuple form.

```
Z,,,,E$
Z
```

Removes the word "espresso" if "solo" or "doppio" is the only other modifier.

```
M(?=[^,]*,\w*$)
MR
```

Appends an `R` to any `M` with only one comma between it and the end of the string. This allows us to transform all `R`s into "drizzle" later on.

```
1(\w*)Y
$1K
K
teen
```

Allows us to transform 14,16,17, and 19 into their word forms all at once, since we replace 4,6,7, and 9 beforehand.

Answer (score 6):

## Javascript ES6, <s>902</s> 900 bytes

```
s=>(R=(l,r)=>(l.split`.`.map((e,i,l)=>!(i%2)&&(r=r.split(e).join(l[i+1]+" "))),r),R("-.no.!.-tuple.1/2.half-caf.1/3.one-third-caf.2/3.two-thirds-caf.ECP.Econ panna.CM.RY.CR.RZ.EM.EY.WC.whip.Wh.whole-milk.A.americano.B.breve.C.cappuccino.D.extra.E.espresso.F.foam.G.grande.H.hazelnut.I.venti.L.latte.M.OZ.N.skim.O.mocha.R.caramel.S.short.T.tall.V.vanilla.X.decaf.Y.macchiato.Z.drizzle.%.two-percent",R(",1,,,,E.solo.,2,,,,E.doppio",s).split`,`.map((e,i)=>(`1VI.2MO.2CR.4xD`.split`.`.map(k=>k[0]==i&&(e=e.split(k[1]).join(k[2]))),i==1?(e=R("1!.single.2!.double.3!.triple.4!.quadruple.5!.quintuple",e.replace(/(\d+)/,"$1!"))):i==2?(e=R("10.ten.20.twenty.11.eleven.12.twelve.13.thir0.14.four0.15.fif0.16.six0.17.seven0.18.eigh0.19.nine0.0.teen.1.one.2.two.3.three.4.four.5.five.6.six.7.seven.8.eight.9.nine",e)):s.includes`E`&&(e=R("single.solo.double.doppio",e)),e)).join` `).replace(/\s+/g," ").trim())
```

"Ungolfed":

```
s=>(
  R=(l,r)=>(l.split`.`.map((e,i,l)=>!(i%2)&&(r=r.split(e).join(l[i+1]+" "))),r),                                   // consecutive string replacement function
  R("-.no.!.-tuple.1/2.half-caf.1/3.one-third-caf.2/3.two-thirds-caf.ECP.Econ panna.CM.RY.CR.RZ.EM.EY.WC.whip.     // replace all symbols with appropriate values
     Wh.whole-milk.A.americano.B.breve.C.cappuccino.D.extra.E.espresso.F.foam.G.grande.H.hazelnut.I.venti.L.latte.
     M.OZ.N.skim.O.mocha.R.caramel.S.short.T.tall.V.vanilla.X.decaf.Y.macchiato.Z.drizzle.%.two-percent",
    R(",1,,,,E.solo.,2,,,,E.doppio",s)                                                                             // if special espresso cases, directly replace entire string
    .split`,`.map((e,i)=>(                                                                                         // split input at commas
      `1VI.2MO.2CR.4xD`.split`.`.map(k=>k[0]==i&&(e=e.split(k[1]).join(k[2]))),                                    // substitute duplicate symbols with unique symbols
      i==1?(e=R("1!.single.2!.double.3!.triple.4!.quadruple.5!.quintuple",e.replace(/(\d+)/,"$1!"))):              // if in shots section, expand all numbers
      i==2?(e=R("10.ten.20.twenty.11.eleven.12.twelve.13.thir0.14.four0.15.fif0.16.six0.17.seven0.18.eigh0.        // if in syrup section, expand all numbers
                  19.nine0.0.teen.1.one.2.two.3.three.4.four.5.five.6.six.7.seven.8.eight.9.nine",e)):
      s.includes`E`&&(e=R("single.solo.double.doppio",e)),                                                         // replace single,double with solo,doppio if espresso is in the string
    e)).join` `).replace(/\s+/g," ").trim())                                                                       // join sections, cleanup whitespaces
```

Example runs:

```
f(",3G,V,Wh,,L")              -> triple grande vanilla whole-milk latte
f("X,2T,,N,,L")               -> decaf double tall skim latte
f("1/2,V,,,,CM")              -> half-caf venti caramel macchiato
f("2/3,3V,3V,B,WC,L")         -> two-thirds-caf triple venti three vanilla breve whip latte
f(",G,,,xCR,CM")              -> grande extra caramel drizzle caramel macchiato
f("X,4T,2M 2C,B,xWC -F xM,C") -> decaf quadruple tall two mocha two caramel breve extra whip no foam extra mocha drizzle cappuccino
f(",2,1V,B,,EM")              -> doppio one vanilla breve espresso macchiato
f(",1,,,,E")                  -> solo
f(",2,,,,E")                  -> doppio
f(",3,,,,E")                  -> triple espresso
```

Comment: Try this: `(R=...)("=-.no.!...` (define R inline then use the result as a function)

Answer (score 4):

## Python, <s>824</s> <s>815</s> <s>807</s> 805 bytes

```
f=lambda s,a=0:a==0and" ".join(" ".join(f(" "+s.split(",")[i],(["X,deC,1/2,half-C,1/3,oneT-C,2/3,twoTs-C,C,caf,T,-third","".join(" %i"%i+f(",%i-tupL,"%i,["1","x","2","y"])for i in range(6,21))+"1,solo,2,doppio,"*('E'in s)+"1,singL,2,doubL, 3,tripL, 4,quadrupL, 5,quintupL,x,1,y,2,S,short,T,tall,G,grande,V,Vnti","V, vanilla,H, hazelnut,10,ten,11,eleVn,12,twelV,13,thirT,14,4T,15,fifT,16,6T,17,7T,18,8een,19,9T,20,twenty,1,one,2,two,3,three,4,four,5,fiV,6,six,7,seVn,8,eight,9,nine,T,teen","Wh,whole-milk,%,two-percent,N,skim,B,breV","x,extra ,-,no ,F,foam,WC,whip,M,MR,R, drizzL","CM,xM,E,espresso,M, macchiato,CP, con panna,A,americano,L,latte,C,cappuccino,x,C"][i]+",C, caramel,M, mocha,L,le ,V,ve").split(","))for i in range(6-(s in",1,,,,E,2,,,,E"))).split())or a and f(s.replace(a[0],a[1]),a[2:])or s
```

Slightly more readable:

```
def f(s,a=0):
 if a==0:
  a=["X,deC,1/2,half-C,1/3,oneT-C,2/3,twoTs-C,C,caf,T,-third"]
  a+=["".join(" %i"%i+f(",%i-tupL,"%i,["1","x","2","y"])for i in range(6,21))+"1,solo,2,doppio,"*('E'in s)+"1,singL,2,doubL, 3,tripL, 4,quadrupL, 5,quintupL,x,1,y,2,S,short,T,tall,G,grande,V,Vnti"]
  a+=["V, vanilla,H, hazelnut,10,ten,11,eleVn,12,twelV,13,thirT,14,4T,15,fifT,16,6T,17,7T,18,8een,19,9T,20,twenty,1,one,2,two,3,three,4,four,5,fiV,6,six,7,seVn,8,eight,9,nine,T,teen"]
  a+=["Wh,whole-milk,%,two-percent,N,skim,B,breV"]
  a+=["x,extra ,-,no ,F,foam,WC,whip,M,MR,R, drizzL"]
  a+=["CM,xM,E,espresso,M, macchiato,CP, con panna,A,americano,L,latte,C,cappuccino,x,C"]
  return" ".join(" ".join(f(" "+s.split(",")[i],(a[i]+",C, caramel,M, mocha,L,le ,V,ve").split(","))for i in range(6-(s in",1,,,,E,2,,,,E"))).split())
 elif a:
  return f(s.replace(a[0],a[1]),a[2:])
 else:
  return s
```

Demo at https://repl.it/C8Hz/3

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-plaF,`, <s>975</s> 870 bytes

I got a random upvote on my old, almost-four-year-old answer to this question, and because of my comments on how horribly it went (you can check the post history if you want to see what I wrote before) I was inspired to make it better (aka: rewrite most of it from the ground up) and managed to golf over a hundred bytes off it. Still longer than the Python answer, but I'm much happier with how things turned out now.

About 20 bytes were saved by switching from trying to run regex patterns to affect specific parts of the comma structure to using the `-aF,` flag to autosplit a line of input on commas and save it to `$F`, allowing me to modify some elements before stitching it back together and finally modifying the output variable with the last few `sub`/`gsub` commands.

Honestly, the number of regex replacements made here means most of this could be a Retina program, but I don't know Retina well enough for that.

```ruby
g=->n,c{n.grep(/^ ?#{c}/i)[0]}
n=%w"0 one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thir four fif";n+=n[6,4]<<'twenty'
$F[1].sub!(/(\d*)(\w)?/){i=eval$1;"#{i&&(%w"0 sing doub trip quadrup quintup"[i]||$1+"-tup")+"le"} #{g[%w"short tall grande venti",$2]if$2}"}
$F[2].gsub!(/(\d*)(\w)/){i=eval$1;"#{i&&n[i]}#{'teen'if(13..19)===i} #{g[%w"vanilla caramel mocha hazelnut",$2]}"}
$F[3].sub!(/.+/){%w"skim whole-milk breve two-percent"[$&.sum%26%4]}
$F[4].gsub!(/(x|-)?(\w+)/){"#{%w"extra no"[$1.ord%2]if$1} #{g[%w"caramelD mochaD whip foam",$2[0]].sub ?D,' drizzle'}"}
$_=$F*' '
sub(/^\S+/){%w"de - half- one-third- two-thirds-"[$&.sum%8]+"caf"}
sub'CP',' con pana'
sub'CM','caramel'+m=' macchiato'
e='espresso'
gsub(/[A-Z]/){g[%w"americano latte cappuccino"+[m,e],$&]}
gsub(/ +/,' ')
$_.strip!
sub(/[sd]...le/){g[%w"doppio solo",$&[0]]}if$_[e]
sub'o '+e,?o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZJhb9MwEIa/91ccWVe3xElJOiEQhAo6Bh8oQoAYIgvIS9zGmmMHx2nLuv51yjndhgRRJNt3vnufO59pL3/t98skeKFovlXh0vB6OP4O06NtvhuLUfoo2/VUcrz2HoFWHOxagy0N57DQrYGFWHFoxAYavuIKuFiWFpRwF91Rdla75hKv2VKYu6iF90z5iUof05Ps@XOCN5T9RXr9szTKwqa9fDAcDy@Kh6PhxXo0HY@2IuErJvvRM@9oKwaDYcfTCLWEQreXYI2o4WfLCtO6VSjb1l4qspubfuR7gTuNfE9ybwdH22WK0U2pjQXLpISlYarggKRWeLQfZ2LRj3feztHEWbj8B@d/GoVKu6MtsZwrIhbDaBKG0dNRkiTiXm/FlJCSQc4Mq7iESuclg5Jdc6la28neSk7uGhD6KOVQr0QF61JLHlRCXsGl4avuIYKamxypvbQ/wJjqOH58fJJ1SU7@cm9ugtEUwX1HjsCYkW@sYaA0BkahNsVxV3N0D3sLeXqgPEVxbO9Cs8px4kR0hDA9pQQKI66vJScd/I@kf/aQAOmhG4fo4tNtBdjdAGuVi8DNUOAGoQi6CrptE9xX8CTzUX2ByTAFmX0gKJFrBTVTjBxsc7TdAhK/SghULM9LwawmPZ4Q3tSGNw0elh1F@jL4liFGVxgGGZEzpUEyazm@Rl23eS6wFX5aUZ7R/gAbeIgEf4zqZIR1hY2bsAeHutKmyMIwlPwua6HrWmhotNTYoIFr0A77@SPlWYesgficTvV@Tydv6Bd6XlL6rveVxp8pfe@20ThGM36zeS8eT@jki/tf0fMZOukbdGxmH53zKz35TN9CPIdoMsMLm/MZBGewmYPz92hMIxdHX897NHIJXzvbYZ10629dW6FVsw9qyc7oHw)

Comment: I'll update acceptance if the status changes!

Comment: Maybe? I'm just not very good at info compression like the other two answers; maybe someone else will be the one to beat Python since this is a very naive solution